# C# Databases Form1 = Datagridview, Form2 = Details View UPDATE/EDIT Method

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, datagridview, detailsview

In my form1 i have my tblContacts in a datagridview, the user can click the button next/previous to navigate through the database. form1 also has an update button which leads to form 2 which is a details view of the same dataset from form1. Can someone tell me how i can make form2 automatically load the contact details of the specific contact that form1 datagridview has been selected on.

Thanks.

Comment: It'd help a lot if we could see your code/database scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly: in your form2 class, create constructors which hold information from the datagrid, for example;

```
public string variable1 {get;set;}
public int variable2 {get;set;}
// as long as they're public, it doesnt matter what you call them, or there type
//(just make sure that you're using the right type, for datagrid's, string is 
//usually fine but you can always convert)
```

secondly: when you create a new instance of your form, you can then assign the variables to "pass" to your new form, like so

```
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
 form2.variable1 = dataSource[rowIndex]["columnName"]
 form2.variable2 = dataSource[rowIndex2]["columnName2"]
```

to get the selected row index, do;

```
dataTable.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

instead of [rowIndex]

From here, in your form2 you can use these values to do whatever you want with them